# Creating Multiple Custom Attibutes For Product with google-api-php-client

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

According to that answer https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/4588281?hl=en-GB

[image: exerpt from google answer]

if I want set multiple promotions ids for the product with the API I can specify multiple lines of:

```
<sc:attribute name="promotion_id">PROMOTION_ID</sc:attribute>
```

I am using this lib https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

My question is how can i do it with this library. Should I use custom attributes? for example.

```
$feed_entry = new Google_Service_Content_Product();

$promotions_ids = array (20,21,22);
foreach ($promotions_ids as $promotion_id ) {
  $promotion = new Google_Service_Content_ProductCustomAttribute();
  $promotion->setName('promotion_id');
  $promotion->setValue($promotion_id);
  $feed_entry->setCustomAttributes($promotion);
}
```

But that would just set this attribute over again for different ids. I am not even sure if I am doing this in a right way. Probably missing something. The full code example would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a definitive code sample for PHP. That being said, if you look at API libraries for other languages you find that:

For **Java** it uses a `List<ProductCustomAttribute>`:

```
public Product setCustomAttributes(java.util.List<ProductCustomAttribute> customAttributes)
```

[Source](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/content/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/content/model/Product.html)

For **JavaScript** it uses a `map`:

```
setCustomAttributes(map)
setCustomAttributes({ 'size': 'Large', 'color': 'Green' })
```

[Source](https://sites.google.com/site/checkoutshoppingcart/javascript-api#TOC-setCustomAttributes-map-)

**Conclusion:**

there's a very good chance the PHP method in question uses an `array` of `Google_Service_Content_ProductCustomAttribute` objects:

> public function setCustomAttributes($customAttributes)

```
$feed_entry = new Google_Service_Content_Product();
$promotions_ids = array (20,21,22);
$customAttributes = array();

foreach ($promotions_ids as $promotion_id ) {
  $promotion = new Google_Service_Content_ProductCustomAttribute();
  $promotion->setName('promotion_id');
  $promotion->setValue($promotion_id);
  $customAttributes[] = $promotion;
}

$feed_entry->setCustomAttributes($customAttributes);
```

Try it!